# Is letting a user call a function though textarea dangerous?

Tags: javascript, textarea, code-injection

Sorry if this has be asked before, but I could not find anything similar to my problem.

I have a website with two textareas - 
One is for MathJax, works pretty similar to this one https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic-2.html

The second textarea is for easy ThreeJS programming. 
So the user can write`sphere1 = new sphere();` press RUN and a 3D sphere appears on the canvas below. 
My page does not have any PHP and i'm not storing the user input anywhere (yet), they are only available for the session.

The function run(); is as follows

```
function run() {
    Clear(); //Removes all objects from the scene
    if (!document.getElementById('newScript')) {
        //if script id doesn't exist it creates new script
        var position = currentPosition(); //Current slide
        var video = $('#slide-' + position).find(".animCode").val();
        var bodyID = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var newScript = document.createElement("script");
        newScript.id = 'newScript';
        newScript.type = "text/javascript";
        newScript.innerHTML = video;
        bodyID.appendChild(newScript);

    } else {
        //else removes previous scripts and overwrites it
        var position = currentPosition(); //Current slide
        var video = $('#slide-' + position).find(".animCode").val();
        var e = document.getElementById('newScript');
        e.id = 'replace';
        var newScript = document.createElement("script");
        newScript.id = 'newScript';
        newScript.type = "text/javascript";
        newScript.innerHTML = video;
        var bodyID = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        bodyID.replaceChild(newScript, e); //remove old script

    }
}
```

My question is: Is this dangerous? I've read a lot about SQL injections but they all talk about data storing in php, which is not my case.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't dangerous, Javascript is a client-side language, any user of your website can see and even execute Javascript on your website through browser console.